# iOS VoIP Push - Failed to Register

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, code-signing

The function

```
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!)
```

Is not being called.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PushKit
import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, PKPushRegistryDelegate  {

var window: UIWindow?

//Tried also to make it local
var voipRegistry:PKPushRegistry?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.registerVoipNotifications()
    return true
}
func registerVoipNotifications() {
    let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()
    // Create a push registry object
    voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry(queue: mainQueue)
    // Set the registry's delegate to self
    voipRegistry!.delegate = self
    // Set the push type to VoIP
    voipRegistry!.desiredPushTypes = [PKPushTypeVoIP]
}
func pushRegistry(registry: PKPushRegistry!, didUpdatePushCredentials credentials: PKPushCredentials!, forType type: String!) {
    //1. Create the alert controller.
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "VoIPPushTest", message: "Token", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    //2. Add the text field. You can configure it however you need.
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in
        textField.text = "got cred"
    })

    //print out the VoIP token. We will use this to test the nofications.
    NSLog("voip token: \(credentials.token)")
    let tokenChars = UnsafePointer<CChar>(credentials.token.bytes)
    var tokenString = ""

    for i in 0..<credentials.token.length {
        tokenString += String(format: "%02.2hhx", arguments: [tokenChars[i]])
    }
    print("Device Token:", tokenString)

}
//Other standard app delegate functions below without changes
```

I read that it may be a certificate problem so

1. Created new app id, profile and certificate
2. Added background capabilities to the app
3. Signing the code with: Code Signing Identity - iPhone Distribution, Provisioning Profile VoIPPushTestProfile

I am archiving the code and exporting for ad hoc deployment. 
What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your code you don't ask the user for permission to receive push notifications. You need to call `UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings` to do so.

Comment: Thank you so much! It may help others to know that it also work in debug mode from code - no need to archive each time.

Comment: Perfect, you can also debug app in kill state, by "Wait for executable to be launched" with distribution certificates.